# How to make a method of an Abstract Class visible in Junit Test Cases in java?

Tags: java, spring, junit

I need to make a method of an abstarct class visible to JUnit Test cases, and that abstract class has been extended to another class, for which I am writing the test cases.

The way of calling that method is given below:

Like as an example I have extended **AbstractWebSocketHandler** to my class and called a method **handleTextMessage** which is protected not public.

And in my class I have called this like :

```
   AbstractWebSocketHandler webSocketHandler = new TextWebSocketHandler() {
@Override
protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
 MY CODE....
}
}
```

I need to write the test cases for this function, but I am not able to access it as it's not visible.

For making it visible I have tried below piece of code:

```
Class<AbstractWebSocketHandler> clazz = AbstractWebSocketHandler.class;
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("handleTextMessage");
        method.setAccessible(true);
```

But no luck.

Can anybody please help me out in this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the reason it is not "visible" is because it is protected. why do you need this anyway? You should not be testing the abstract class, but the child class(es)

Comment: You could create the test class under the same package as that abstract class, and that should give it automatic access to protected members.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to test the method but access is not `public`.

`JUnit` have a limited of `@Test`, the access modifier have to be `public`.

You can create a class between abstract to override access modifier.

## Example

### Abstract Class

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    protect abstract void abstractMethod();
}
```

### Proxy Class

```
public abstract class ProxyParentClass extends AbstractClass {
   @Override
   public abstract void abstractMethod();
}
```

### SubClass

```
public class SubClass extends ProxyParentClass{

    @Test
    @Override
    public void abstractMethod() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```